# paragraph text for modal box not aligning in center using css and asp.net

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have a problem where even if i use the text-align property and equals it to center, the text in my modal box, which is the upload successful inside the paragraph tag, is not changing anything. It is still at the leftside of the modal box. I want it to be in the center. Kindly help me on this one.

Here is the aspx code:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
                   <!-- Modal content -->
                   <div class="modal-content">
                      <span class="close">&times;</span><br />
                      <p>Upload Successful</p>
                   </div>
              </div>
```

Here is the css:

```
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 50%;
}

.modal-content p{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Here is also an image of the modal box:

[image]

Comment: The text is already in the center of the model box. Can you please create a fiddle or share a screen?

Comment: @kravisingh - i have added an image in my question just now. Kindly check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inspect your code and check other css codes that contributes on  tag `p`. it seems other css codes are changing its style.

for example, search for finding something like `display: inline-block;` that is attached to  `p` tag.

Comment: your right! i simply just added an id and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Add this first:

```
.modal-content p{
  display: block; 
  width: 100%;
 }
```

And if it still not works then use `!important`

```
 .modal-content p{
  display: block !important; 
  width: 100% !important;
 }
```